# Set max height for listview

Tags: android, listview, height

Something really stupid, but I want to set a maximum height for my listview and I don't seem to find something that works. Some talk of setting a maxheight to the listview, but I am not able to find this option? 
I now have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="40dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvSwitch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when there is only one item in the list, it is still has a height of 120dp, which isn't necessary then of course, it just cannot exceed that height...

Comment: Hi you should use android:layout_weight="1" for listview, look at my answer please

Comment: @Talha This cannot be achieved in the context of the given layout. layout_weight is useless when there is no other item in the LinearLayout. You need at least two items for it to have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content".
```

Edit:
you could check the number of items in your listview and set the size in case its higher than 20. Something like:

```
if(numberOfItems>20){
listview.setWidth(yourSize)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: Some explanation perhaps? What is the maximum height in this case set to? 1?

Answer (score 0):

Together with, or instead of `android:layout="120dp"` try `android:minHeight="20dp"`, assuming 20dp is the height of a single list item. That way if the ListView has 1 or 2 things it wont take up the whole 120dp.